Display the Remaining Stock Quantity for each order item only in WooCommerce new order email notification
I'm having a small issue with a code snippet that is displaying the remaining product stock quantity for each order item in Admin New Order email notification.
This is my code:
// Add action to display content on specific email
 add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'add_stock_to_admin_email', 20, 4 );
    
    // Function to display content on specific email
    function add_stock_to_admin_email( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
        if ( $email->id == 'new_order' ) {
            // Add action to display remaining stock quantity on order item meta
            add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_start', 'display_remaining_stock_quantity', 10, 3 );
        }
    }
    
    // Function to display remaining stock quantity on order item meta
    function display_remaining_stock_quantity(int $item_id, object $item, object $order): void {
        // Only display for line items
        if (!$item->is_type('line_item')) {
            return;
        }
    
        $product = $item->get_product();
    
        // Display remaining stock quantity
        $stock_quantity = $product->get_stock_quantity();
        if ($stock_quantity > 0) {
            printf('<div>%s: %d</div>', __('Remaining stock', 'woocommerce'), $stock_quantity);
        }
    }

This works fine to add the remaining stock line under each product in the order product table. However it is also adding the remaining stock to customer emails when paid by Bank Deposit/ Order on hold emails etc. which I dont want. It should ideally be added only to that first New Order Notification that is sent to admins.
I am clearly missing something? Some assistance would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

I tested your code and there is no such issue as you describe… "The remaining stock" is only displayed on new order notification (sent to the admin) for each order item...

@LoicTheAztec thank you for taking the time to check this for me. I was pretty sure it was all good as well. But for any Direct Bank Transfers that puts the Order on Hold sends the customer a new order with the remaining stock and its doing my head. Screenshot of email received here : https://imgur.com/a/OHqmiN4

I tested that case too, and I don't get any issue as you describe. So there is something else that is making trouble. I have answered your question below, providing an alternative code solution, that uses something different.

Yes, sorry all of that is unnecessary. I've edited the code now. I was just trying everything to get it working and pasted that instead when making the thread. I have no idea why but its started working now. Idk if it was some weird caching issue or something but I just deleted everything and started fresh and it works! Thank you for your time as always!

Actually it didn't work. Works only if I manually create an order. Going to try your solution now.

An alternative way:
There is an alternative code solution that I have already used before. Try the following:
// Setting the email ID as a global variable
add_action('woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'set_the_email_id_as_a_global_variable', 1, 4);
function set_the_email_id_as_a_global_variable($order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email){
    $GLOBALS['email_id_str'] = $email->id;
}

// Display product remaining stock quantity on order items
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_start', 'display_remaining_stock_quantity', 10, 3 );
function display_remaining_stock_quantity( $item_id, $item, $order ) {
    // Only for order item "line item" type
    if ( !$item->is_type('line_item') ) {
        return;
    }
    $globalsVar = $GLOBALS; // Pass $GLOBALS variable as reference

    // Try to get the email ID from globals reference 
    if( isset($globalsVar['email_id_str']) && $globalsVar['email_id_str'] === 'new_order' ) {
        $product = $item->get_product();

        if ( $stock_qty = $product->get_stock_quantity() ) {
            printf('<div>%s: %d</div>', __('Remaining stock', 'woocommerce'), $stock_qty);
        }
    }
}

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works. It may work on your side, avoiding the issue you describe.

Some related answers:

Customize order item meta only for WooCommerce admin email notifications
Customizing footer text email notiications based on user role in Woocommerce
Get the customer user_id in Woocommerce email footer template
Add shipping class under items in New Order email in WooCommerce?
Add a custom text for a particular product on specific email notification in Woocommerce
Add the product description to WooCommerce email notifications

